# Can one use SOS pad on Gotham frying pan?

Tags: cleaning

Stains remaining in frying pan after cooking meat that sticks to the pan. I have tried [SOS pads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.O.S_Soap_Pad), is that okay?

Answer (score 4):

SOS pads are steel wool with a ton of soap. That means they are an abrasive cleaner, and except on the very hardest surfaces, will scratch away the surface. This makes them very effective so removing a microscopic portion of a stainless steel pan or a slightly less microscopic portion of an aluminum pan (or cookie sheet) is sometimes worth it.

I believe those pans are coated with some form of porcelain, which is a very hard surface. So you're probably removing very little of that surface, but if that's the way you clean it every time — you will eventually destroy the pan.

You may want to consider plain stainless, high-carbon steel, or cast iron. The later two are seasoned with oil and become non-stick. Also... minor stains (on any type of pan) can often just be ignored.

Comment: Why do you think "those pans are coated with some form of porcelain" ?

Comment: @LyndonWhite their site says ceramic, not sure why I said porcelain (a particular type of ceramic).